# Multiple 'or' statements resulting in a Boolean method always returning true. Why?

Tags: java

```
    import java.util.*;

    public class help {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            System.out.print(isAllVowels("ugh".toLowerCase()));
        }

        public static boolean isAllVowels(String Str) {
            if( Str.length() == 0) {
                return true;
            }
            int b = Str.length();
            for( int a=0; a<b; a++) {
                char c = Str.charAt(a);
                if(c!='a' || c!='e' || c !='i' || c!='o' || c!='u') {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Hi there, I'm new to java and the char comparing element that returns true always does so. I was wondering why it always does so? Additinally IntelliJ tells me that a is always less than b. Why is that so?
Thanks.

Comment: With regard to your second question, I believe the reason a is always < b is related to what others have pointed out: the if statement with all the or's will always evaluate to true. Because of this, the "for (int a=0; a<b; a++)" loop will only ever execute once (because the if statement is always true and will immediately go to the return true, which breaks out of the loop), meaning that a will only ever be 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are expecting the code to return true if all the characters in the string 
are vowels and false if any one of the character is no-vowel,
 check the following code.

```
public class help
    {
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            System.out.print(isAllVowels("aseiou".toLowerCase()));
        }
        public static boolean isAllVowels(String Str)
        {
        if( Str.length() == 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        for( int a=0; a<Str.length(); a++)
        {
            char c = Str.charAt(a);
            if(c=='a' || c=='e' || c =='i' || c=='o' || c=='u')
            {
                continue;
            }
            else  return false;

        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for the information. You showed me the new 'continue' command. I did research on that, and I'm sure it will help me further down Java.

Comment: You are welcome and thanks for the opportunity to share and gain knowledge.

Answer (score 6):

The problem isn't that you're using a ton of `or` statements.

You're confusing the meaning of `and` and `or`. `and` is exclusive, returning true if both conditions are satisfied. `or` is inclusive, returning true if either condition is satisfied.

Think about it like this: let's say you need to buy a new pair of shoes, but you're picky. The shoes must be blue `and` suede. A pair of blue Chuck Taylor All-Stars satisfies the first condition, but not the second. Will you buy the Chucks? False. Someone robs Graceland and steals a pair of Elvis Presley's shoes and offers them to you. The shoes are blue `and` suede. Will you buy them? True.

If you're a less picky person, you'll take blue shoes `or` suede shoes. Blue Chucks, brown suede loafers, tan suede slippers, or blue flip flops all meet one of two criteria, and will therefore be true.

Your code, in plain English, is asking "if the character is not `a`, `e`, `i`, `o` or `u`, return true." Even though `u` is a vowel, `u` is not `a`, not `e`, not `i` and not `o`, so it returns true.

Using a bunch of `or` just means if any one of those conditions is true, then return true.

Comment: Many thanks, I didn't understand what was wrong with my logic before. :)

Answer (score 0):

The program is running as expected.
The condition 
`if(c!='a' || c!='e' || c !='i' || c!='o' || c!='u')` will return true for your given input.